# PHP С помощью чего лучше реализовать работу с датами и временем?

Tags: php, mysql, время, datetime

Что лучше использовать для решения таких задач в PHP (mysqL):

1. Нужно вывести на сайте текущую телепередачу (имея datetime её начала и конца)
2. Вывести на сайте телепередачи на сегодня, завтра послезавтра (имея datetime их начала и конца)
3. Вывести телепередачу которая идет сейчас и будет идти после неё. (имея datetime их начала и конца)

То есть мне нужно будет проверять, входит ли актуальная дата в какой-то определенный диапазон. В Python я бы использовал для этой цели модуль time. А что для этого можно использовать в PHP? И можно ли пример?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.datetime.php

Comment: а что вы хотите сделать на пхп такое, чего в данном вопросе нельзя достичь средствами самой СУБД ?